# How can I convert column inputs into column names in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation

| REGION | WEIGHT_CONDITION | MEAN_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Northeast | UnderWeight | 30 |
| Northeast | NormalWeight | 75 |
| Northeast | OverWeight | 52 |
| Southwest | UnderWeight | 44 |
| Southwest | NormalWeight | 68 |
| Southwest | OverWeight | 72 |

**How can I convert this top table into:**

| Weight_Condition | Northeast | Southwest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UnderWeight | 30 | 44 |
| NormalWeight | 75 | 68 |
| OverWeight | 52 | 72 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(df1, names_from = REGION, values_from = MEAN_VALUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  WEIGHT_CONDITION Northeast Southwest
  <chr>                <int>     <int>
1 UnderWeight             30        44
2 NormalWeight            75        68
3 OverWeight              52        72
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
tapply(df1$MEAN_VALUE, df1[2:1], I)
                REGION
WEIGHT_CONDITION Northeast Southwest
    NormalWeight        75        68
    OverWeight          52        72
    UnderWeight         30        44
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(REGION = c("Northeast", "Northeast", "Northeast", 
"Southwest", "Southwest", "Southwest"), WEIGHT_CONDITION = c("UnderWeight", 
"NormalWeight", "OverWeight", "UnderWeight", "NormalWeight", 
"OverWeight"), MEAN_VALUE = c(30L, 75L, 52L, 44L, 68L, 72L)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you! That 'values_from=' argument is so critical.